# XmlSerializer.setProperty throwing exception

Tags: java, android, xml

When I try to set a property for my XmlSerializer, e.g.

```
xmlSerializer.setProperty("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#serializer-line-separator", "\n");
```

the program throws "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported Property:".  I looked at xmlpull.org and confirmed that the file properties.html doesn't seem to exist.  Am I missing something here?

If this no longer works for some reason, is there any other way to format a programatically generated XML without manually inserting all the formatting myself?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem

This is works for me:

```
xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
```